# Field extension equality using Kronecker theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

[Kronecker's theorem](http://feyzioglu.boun.edu.tr/book/chapter5/ch5%2851%29.pdf) says that a field extension can be shown as say,
F(a) represented as F[x]/minimalpoly(a).

Say, Q[$\sqrt{2}$]=Q[x]/$(x^{2}-2$)

And a well known example is Q[$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$]=Q[$\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}$]

But the minimum polys I will get will be different for both.

Minpoly for Q[$\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}$] = $x^{4}-4x^{2}+1$ and

Q[$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$] = $x^{4}-10x^{2}+1$

So,

- Is it that there are multiple generators for the same field
  extension.
- How the minimum poly is different from ideals?
- How this representation help more?

Comment: "But the minimum polys I will get will be different for both." Minimal polynomials of what over what?

Comment: I don't think Kronecker's Theorem (**this** Kroneceker theorem)  says that. It says that any non-constant polynomial over any field $\;F\;$ has a root in some field extension $\;K\;$  of $\;F\;$ . The form of the extension is sometimes added to the theorem, but I think it is rather part of the proof. Also, what *exactly* is the question?

Comment: The first one is $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^4-10 x^2+1)$ while the second one is $\Bbb Q[y, z]/(y^2 - 2, z^2 - 3)$. Yes, the polynomials are different, but the resulting fields are isomorphic, and when viewed as subfields of $\Bbb R$ they're even equal.

Comment: @Arthur: Thanks, could you please help with some elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

Take an even simpler example. As fields, $$\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]= \mathbb Q[\sqrt 2+1]=\mathbb Q[a\sqrt2+b]$$ for any rational numbers $a,b$.

The point is, given a choice of generator $\alpha$ of a field $K$ over $\mathbb Q$ (so $K=\mathbb Q[\alpha]$), we can find the minimal polynomial $f(X)$ of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb Q$ and write
$$K=\mathbb Q[\alpha]\cong \mathbb Q[X]/(f(X)).$$
However, the choice of polynomial depends entirely on the choice of $\alpha$, and this choice is far from unique.

This is analogous to choosing a basis of a vector space. Given an abstract vector space $V$ over a field $k$, we can *choose* a basis of $V$, which is the same as specifying an isomorphism $V\cong k^{\dim V}$.

Comment: If you could shows a complete example that also includes proving this isomorphism, it could be more helpful.

Comment: Which isomorphism are you unclear about? The fields $\mathbb Q[\sqrt2]=\mathbb Q[\sqrt2+1]$ are equal as sets. As such, the identity map is an isomorphism.

Comment: I read theorem that if two basis have same dimension, then they are isomorphic, may be I will accept it and proceed with it.

Comment: I think I've made things confusing by talking about isomorphisms. $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ and $\mathbb Q[\sqrt +1]$ are *equal* as sets. I think if the relationship between the two as an equality (with a different choice of generator), not as an isomorphsim